# How switch Bootstrap 5 tabs (button version) with javascipt

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, button, tabs, bootstrap-5

I want to programmable switch tabs (using bootstrap 5). Bootsrap docs say:

> As a best practice, we recommend using  elements for the tabs,
> as these are controls that trigger a dynamic change, rather than links
> that navigate to a new page or location.

So I want use buttons instead links. Code:

```js
$("#mybut").click(function() {
  var sel = document.querySelector('#nav-tab-manager')
  bootstrap.Tab.getInstance(sel).show()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>

<div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
  <button class="nav-link active" id="nav-tabs-order" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tabs-1" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="tabs-1" aria-selected="true">Orders
  </button>
  <button class="nav-link" id="nav-tab-manager" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tabs-2" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="tabs-2" aria-selected="false">Managers
  </button>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tabs-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tabs-tab1">
    Orders
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabs-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tabs-2">
    Managers
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="mybut">Want switch to manager</button>
```

Problem is wrong selector. But I have no idea why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use `getOrCreateInstance` instead because the Tabs aren't being first initialized via JS.

```
$("#mybut").click(function() {
  var sel = document.querySelector('#nav-tab-manager')
  bootstrap.Tab.getOrCreateInstance(sel).show()
})
```

https://codeply.com/p/kjHOlPJFnN